# Have DefinePlugin apply to sub dependencies?

Tags: webpack

DefinePlugin seems to only work with my own code, but not on external modules that I am importing

Is there a way to say "please apply to this npm module too"?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, DefinePlugin works globally. In fact, I only added it to a project after Redux started complaining that `process.env.NODE_ENV` should be `"production"` when the bundle is minified. The warning was gone once I added the plugin.

Based on that, I assume something else is at fault in your case.